# Importing multiple csv files, manipulate(filter a column and do a summary) and export the results in one txt file

Tags: r, csv

I have code here I am trying to manipulte my files so that the one column is only 1 and not 1 and 0. I have multiple files and multiple columns but regardless filtering one column to get only 1's and keeping everything else should be easy to do. I can not get the dplyr function to work with d %>% filter(CreaseUp>0). Maybe there is another command with lapply that would work? everything else works. I can get the files summarized and outputted in one file. I'm so close to getting this right. Please help.

```
setwd("~/OneDrive/School/R/R Workspace/2016_Coda-Brundage/cb")
#assuming your working directory is the folder with the CSVs
f = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
for (i in 1:length(f)) assign(f[i], read.csv(f[i]))
d<-lapply(f, read.csv)
f.1<-d %>% 
    filter(CreaseUp>0)
w<-lapply(f.1, summary)
write.table(w, file = "SeedScan_results1.csv", sep = ",", col.names = NA,
        qmethod = "double")
```

Final script. I had to open the .txt file in office, change the spaces inbetween the headings and numbers to commas and then create a table from text. From there i could put it in excel and pull my means from this set.

```
setwd("~/OneDrive")
#assuming your working directory is the folder with the CSVs
f=list.files(pattern="*.csv")
library(dplyr)
sink("SeedScan_results1.txt")
for (i in 1:length(f)){
df=assign(f[i], read.csv(f[i]))
df=filter(df, CreaseUp>0)
print(lapply(df, summary))
}
sink(NULL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `d` seems to be a list of dataframes, not a dataframe, so `dplyr` can't handle it. Also, what is that loop doing now? Why not put the read (and possibly filtering) inside the loop?

```
alldfs = NULL
for (i in f){
    df = read.csv(i)
    df = filter(df, CreaseUp>0)
    alldfs = bind_rows(alldfs, df)
}
# print summary etc.
```

EDIT - if you want to print the summary from within the loop:

```
sink("SeedScan_results1.txt")
for (i in f){
    df = read.csv(i)
    df = filter(df, CreaseUp>0)
    print(lapply(df, summary))
}
sink(NULL)
```

The `append` flag might be helpful if you want to move `sink` inside the loop.

Comment: So this worked with filtering my CreaseUp so they are > 0. However, since i dont want to bind the files together. I will let lapply do that when i do the summarys. So i #alldfs=bind_rows(alldfs, df). As a results it only outputed my first csv file with the Crease Up sorted but didnt do a summary for all my csv's and output them in the same file like it did before. How do i get it to do for all csv's becuase it only did it for the first csv.

Comment: setwd("~/OneDrive/School/R/R Workspace/2016_Coda-Brundage/cb")
#assuming your working directory is the folder with the CSVs
f=list.files(pattern="*.csv")
alldfs=NULL
for (i in f){
  df=read.csv(i)
  df=filter(df, CreaseUp>0)
  #alldfs= bind_rows(alldfs, df)
  lapply(df, summary)
}

write.table(df, file = "SeedScan_results1.csv", sep = ",", col.names = NA,
            qmethod = "double")

Comment: Initially I wanted to import the csv files, do the CreaseUp>0 to each of them individually then export them indiviually in csv files. Reimport them and do the lapply to get the summarys and export as one csv file.

Comment: @Jacob your `lapply(df, summary)` output isn't assigned to anything, and printing to console is suppressed within loops. You need to either `print(lapply(df, summary))`, or store it somewhere. I edited the post - see if that is what you wanted.

Comment: Yes it worked finally. one last thing, It printed in the console, but I want to write the output in a csv file. I tried using the write.table(sumTable, file ="SeedScan_results1.csv", sep=",", 
              col.names=F, qmethod ="double", append=T) insdie the for loop. This outputed an error: Error in provideDimnames(x, sep = sep, base = base) : 
  'dimnames' applied to non-array. How do I get this the stuff in the consol to print to csv file?

Comment: setwd("~/OneDrive/School/R/R Workspace/2016_Coda-Brundage/cb")
#assuming your working directory is the folder with the CSVs
f=list.files(pattern="*.csv")
library(dplyr)
alldfs=NULL
for (i in f){
  df=read.csv(i)
  df=filter(df, CreaseUp>0)
  sumTable<-print(lapply(df, summary))
  write.table(sumTable, file ="SeedScan_results1.csv", sep=",", 
              col.names=F, qmethod ="double", append=T)
}

Comment: I tried your edit too but it reported the same error

Comment: @Jacob oh yeah, since `summary` produces a list, not a table or dataframe, you cannot save it with `write` functions. (and it's not really a .csv file that we end up writing.) Edited my post to use `sink` - it simply redirects all output to a file, so it's insensitive to formatting, but you might want to move it inside the loop if you generate some output that shouldn't be stored. `sink(NULL)` turns the redirection off.

Comment: Awesome, It worked. I just had to do some table building in office and now it's in excel. Thanks for your help!